# Bootstrap file is not readable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/map.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    </head>
```

now where should i add the bootstrap files i have added above the style.css file but its showing fele not readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the default Bootstrap folder structure, and *if* your HTML file is in the root, then you would add something like:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

in your head section. The JavaScript file should come after the jQuery references, and the CSS file generally goes before any custom CSS file.

For example:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/map.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

(BTW, I removed one of your Font Awesome stylesheets in the above; make sure that the other one points to a valid path as it's not in the same folder as the rest of your CSS)

Comment: can you tell me where to include in the above code i mentioned??

Comment: Updated version included now :-)